# Dynamically add CSS class to out of stock product images (WordPress,MarketPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using MarketPress by WPMUDev for WordPress and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to add a class to an image depending on if it's out of stock or not.

I have working code which returns if products are out of stock so that's not the issue.

I'm looking to apply a CSS class on the product list page to the thumbnail of each product using this logic:

if $stock == 0 then apply $cssClass1 else apply $cssClass2.

MarketPress seems to generate it's image thumbnails and product list using the following:

```
if (!function_exists('mp_product_image')) :

/*
 * Displays the product featured image
 *
 * @param bool $echo Optional, whether to echo
 * @param string $context Options are list, single, or widget
 * @param int $post_id The post_id for the product. Optional if in the loop
 * @param int $size An optional width/height for the image if contect is widget
 * @param string $align The alignment of the image. Defaults to settings.
 */

function mp_product_image($echo = true, $context = 'list', $post_id = NULL, $size = NULL, $align = NULL) {

        global $id, $mp;
        $post_id = ( NULL === $post_id ) ? $id : $post_id;

        // Added WPML
        $post_id = apply_filters('mp_product_image_id', $post_id);
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        $class = $title = $link = '';

        $img_classes = array('mp_product_image_' . $context, 'photo', StockCheck::fetchNewStock($imgGGClass));

        if ( !is_null($align) )

            $align = 'align' . $align;

        if ($context == 'list') {

                //quit if no thumbnails on listings
                if (!$mp->get_setting('show_thumbnail'))
                        return '';

                //size
                if (intval($size)) {
                        $size = array(intval($size), intval($size));
                } else {
                        if ($mp->get_setting('list_img_size') == 'custom')
                                $size = array($mp->get_setting('list_img_width'), $mp->get_setting('list_img_height'));
                        else
                                $size = $mp->get_setting('list_img_size');
                }

                //link
                $link = get_permalink($post_id);
                $title = esc_attr($post->post_title);
                $class = ' class="mp_img_link"';
                $img_classes[] = is_null($align) ? $mp->get_setting('image_alignment_list') : $align;

        } else if ($context == 'single') {

                //size
                if ($mp->get_setting('product_img_size') == 'custom')
                        $size = array($mp->get_setting('product_img_width'), $mp->get_setting('product_img_height'));
                else
                        $size = $mp->get_setting('product_img_size');

                //link
                $temp = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'large');
                $link = $temp[0];

                if ($mp->get_setting('disable_large_image')) {
                        $link = '';
                        $title = esc_attr($post->post_title);
                } else {
                        $title = __('View Larger Image &raquo;', 'mp');
                }

                $class = ' class="mp_product_image_link mp_lightbox"';
                $img_classes[] = is_null($align) ? $mp->get_setting('image_alignment_single') : $align;

                //in case another plugin is loading lightbox
                if ($mp->get_setting('show_lightbox')) {
                    $class .= ' rel="lightbox"';
                    wp_enqueue_script('mp-lightbox');
                }

        } else if ($context == 'widget') {

                //size
                if (intval($size))
                        $size = array(intval($size), intval($size));
                else
                        $size = array(50, 50);

                //link
                $link = get_permalink($post_id);
                $title = esc_attr($post->post_title);
                $class = ' class="mp_img_link"';
        }

        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size, array('itemprop' => 'image', 'class' => implode(' ', $img_classes), 'title' => $title));

        if (empty($image) && $context != 'single') {
                if (!is_array($size)) {
                        $size = array(get_option($size . "_size_w"), get_option($size . "_size_h"));
                }

                    $img_classes[] = 'wp-post-image';

                $image = '

                    <div itemscope class="hmedia">
                        <span class="fn">' . get_the_title(get_post_thumbnail_id()) . '</span>
                        <img width="' . $size[0] . '" height="' . $size[1] . '" itemprop="image" title="' . esc_attr($title) . '" class="' . implode(' ', $img_classes) . '" src="' . apply_filters('mp_default_product_img', $mp->plugin_url . 'images/default-product.png') . '" />
                    </div>';
        }

        //force ssl on images (if applicable) http://wp.mu/8s7
        if ( is_ssl() ) {
            $image = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $image);
        }

        //add the link
        if ($link) {
            $image = '

                <div itemscope class="hmedia">
                    <div style="display:none"><span class="fn">' . get_the_title(get_post_thumbnail_id()) . '</span></div>
                    <a rel="lightbox enclosure" id="product_image-' . $post_id . '"' . $class . ' href="' . $link . '">' . $image . '</a>
                </div>';
        }

        $image = apply_filters('mp_product_image', $image, $context, $post_id, $size);

        if ($echo)
            echo $image;
        else
            return $image;
}
endif;
```

I have tried the following (where the StockCheck bit adds text to a variable depending on the stock value):

```
$img_classes = array('mp_product_image_' . $context, 'photo', StockCheck::fetchNewStock($imgGGClass));
```

However the above only applies one class or another to all thumbnails on the list page, it doesn't apply depending on whether the item is in stock.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks